# Как в проводнике vs code убрать отступы у файлов возникающие при использовании тем значков в которых есть значки для папок?

Tags: visual-studio-code

У всех тем значков в которых присутствуют значки для папок, у файлов появляется лишний отступ размером в саму иконку. Для более наглядного примера я установил значение отступов для дерева (workbench.tree.indent) значение 0. Все папки и файлы при такой настройке должны выстроиться в 1 линию. Но если в теме значков у папок присутствуют значки то у файлов появляется отступ. Как настроить (убрать) этот отступ?

Изображения сделаны при одинаковых настройках, но с разными темами значков. На 2 изображении наглядно виден ненужный отступ у файлов.

[image]

[image]

Comment: то есть, Вы хотите имена файлов с их иконками подвинуть чуть влево?

Comment: Верно, на то же место как и на 1 изображении. При этом папки с их иконками должны остаться на своих местах.

Comment: попробуйте отрицательный отступ, но что то мне кажется, что это вряд ли

Comment: Отступы чего? Если Вы имеете ввиду workbench.tree.indent то это другая настройка которая не имеет отношение к этим отступам. Даже если бы отрицательные значения работали то это подвинет и папки что не нужно, а также эта настройка нужна по её прямому назначению.